# Group letters 2 by 2

Tags: c++, c

I need some help.
I need to make a program, and that program must make group of all letters in the alphabet , my ideea is the next (C++):

```
  #include <string.h>
  #include <iostream>

  int main()
  {
    char i,j,word[2];
    for(i='a';i<='z';i++)
      for(j='a';j<='z';j++)
      {
         strcpy(word,i);
         strcat(word,j);
         cout<<word<<"\n";
      }
  }
```

Unfortunately, that program didn't work,because `i` and `j` isn't a constant char so `i` and `j` can't be mmade part of function strcpy/ strcat. I don't have any ideea, please help me if you have.

Comment: Are you committed to using `strcat` and `strcpy`?  They're not very good for this job.

Comment: Your `word[2]` is too short.

Comment: `strcpy` is for copying null-terminated strings, not for writing characters one by one.

Comment: @deviantfan word[2] isn't too short because I need to make gorup of letters 2 by 2 so I`ll have something like that aa ab ac ...zz.

Comment: Make decision do you want c or c++, if c++ you should incude `<cstring>` not `<string.h>`

Comment: @Mecanicul Yes, it is too short. You'll need a `word[3]` for that. Please, if you don't know anything about C strings, don't use them.

Comment: @E_net4 can you tell me another function of how to make group 2 by 2 but I need that group of chars chars to be in a vector?

Comment: @Mecanicul You don't need any function, just normal assignments. And I don't see a vector in your code.

Comment: @deviantfan word[2] will have word[0] and word[1] exact 2 elements

Comment: Sadly `std::combinations` hasn't been added yet :) http://paste.ubuntu.com/12775892/

Comment: @Mecanicul Yes, so what? Repeat, please learn about C strings *before* using them.

Comment: @Mecanicul You don't understand what C strings are.  They must be terminated with a NULL character.  It isn't just two characters.  It is *three* characters:  Example: `a, b, \0`.  Understand now?  Every book on 'C' that I know of explains this plainly and simply.  If you feed `strcpy` and `strcat` char arrays that are not null-terminated, those functions search and will not stop until it finds a null byte, and who knows where they will find one.  That's why you must *explicitly* put a null there in the 3rd slot in the array.

Answer (score 7):

You can just print it.. no need for a variable.

```
for(i='a';i<='z';i++)
  for(j='a';j<='z';j++)
  {
     cout<< i << j <<"\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: I need them every group to be in that word[2] then resset then another group of 2 will be in that vector, this was just a part of my problem

Comment: what's wrong with word[0] = i; word[1] = j; ?

Comment: @Mecanicul If `word[2]` and the cout are required, your assignment is impossible. Even if you don't want to believe us. And there is no vector (http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) in your code.

Comment: You could change the output to `cout << word[0] << word[1] << '\n';`